# Installing VM on CentOS 6.6 with virt-install hangs

Tags: linux, centos, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, virsh

I'm trying to install a Centos 6.6 VM on a CentOS 6.6 host with the following command.

```
virt-install \
--name vm-queue \
--description "Queue Server" \
--ram 2048 \
--disk path=/var/kvm/images/vm-queue.img,size=30 \
--vcpus 2 \
--os-type linux \
--os-variant rhel6 \
--network bridge=br0 \
--graphics none \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--cdrom /var/iso/CentOS-6.6-x86_64-minimal.iso
```

I'm given a boot screen letting me choose an install option.

[image]

As soon as I press enter, I'm given

```
Loading vmlinuz......
Loading initrd.img....................................ready.
Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok
```

I then get a cursor in the bottom left hand corner, and about 3-4 seconds later I am presented with `�`.

[image]

I've let it sit for as long as an hour and nothing happens.

As far as I know, everything in that install line is cool. The machine has 2 4-core processors, 96G of ram, the bridge is working.

`/var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log` doesn't get anything during the install. However, when I end up having to <kbd>Enter</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to terminate the session I'm given

```
14232: error : daemonStreamHandleAbort:609 : stream aborted at client request
14232: error : virNetSocketReadWire:1194 : End of file while reading data: Input/output error
```

and then when I kill the process.

```
14232: error : qemuMonitorIO:615 : internal error End of file from monitor
```

Anyone know whats up with the random character I get while trying to install?

In case anyone needs it, heres the XML file that is created by libvirt

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>vm-queue</name>
  <uuid>de964c10-fdc3-ddad-96d3-c885bd9c1661</uuid>
  <description>Queue Server</description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel6.6.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/var/kvm/images/vm-queue.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:bd:ac:6e'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to install using a serial console, rather than a *normal* console. Not sure *why* you're doing that, but...

By default the installer tries to display either text or graphics on the Linux console. To divert output to the *serial* console you need to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the boot screen, and ensure that you add the following options to the boot command line:

```
text console=ttyS0
```

Comment: This works. I am redirecting to a serial console because i am SSH'd into the machine im trying to install things on. (at least thats the reason I *think* im using a serial console) I dont fully understand this whole process yet. This is all for learning purposes. Thank you!

Comment: I generally run virt-manager on my local workstation and have it ssh-tunnel to the remote server. This lets me have full consoles, a nice GUI for managing the hypervisor, etc.

Comment: Never even installed virt-manager because I didnt know it could remotely edit things. That is indeed way easier, thanks!